# Why p:inputTextArea value is not set?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this form:

```html
<h:form id="productsForm">
 <p:dialog id="newProductDlg">
  <p:panelGrid>
   <p:outputLabel value="Name:"/>
    <p:inputText id="newProductName" value="#{productService.name}" />

    <p:outputLabel value="Category:"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="parentCategoryList"
     value="#{productService.category}">
     <f:selectItems var="currCateg" itemLabel="#{currCateg}"
      value="#{categoryService.categories}" itemValue="#{currCateg}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputLabel value="Price:"/>
    <p:spinner id="priceSpinner" value="#{productService.price}"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="Specifications:"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Add specifications"
     title="Open 'Add specifications' dialog"/>

    <f:facet name="footer">   
                  <p:commandButton id="addNewProductBtn" value="Add new product"
      process="productsForm:specificationsArea productsForm:newProductDlg"
      actionListener="#{productService.createProduct}"/>
     <p:commandButton id="cancelAddingProd" value="Cancel"/>
    </f:facet>
   </p:panelGrid>
  </p:dialog>

  <p:dialog id="newSpecificationDlg">
   <p:panelGrid>
    <p:outputLabel value="Title:"/>
    <p:inputText id="newSpecificationTitle"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="Description:"/>
    <p:inputText id="newSpecificationDesc"/>

    <f:facet name="footer">
     <p:inputTextarea readonly="true" autoResize="false" 
                        rows="7" id="specificationsArea"
      value="#{productService.specifications}">
     </p:inputTextarea>

     <p:commandButton value="Add new specification entry" id="addNewSpecifEntryBtn"
      update="productsForm:specMessages"
                      process="newSpecificationTitle newSpecificationDesc specMessages"/>

     <p:commandButton id="cancelAddingSpecif" value="Back"
      styleClass="CategDlgBtn dlgField" type="button"/>
    </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
  </p:dialog>
 </h:form>
```

Here, `textArea` is something like `template` that show us how values will be displayed on another page. That is why it is `readonly`.

It works as follows:
1) In main dialog (`newProductDlg`) I write `name`, `category` and `other` parameters,
2) I can open second dialog (`newSpecificationDlg`) and write there new specifications,
3) In `newSpecificationDlg` are two inputs `newSpecificationTitle` and `newSpecificationDesc`. If I press `addNewSpecifEntryBtn` value of `specificationsArea` is appended by values of these two inputs via javascript:

```
var title = newSpecificationTitle.value, desc = newSpecificationDesc.value;
if (title == null || desc == null || title.length == 0 || desc.length == 0)
    return;
specificationsArea.value = specificationsArea.value + title + ' : ' + desc
        + ';\n';
```

In this case `setter` for `specifications` is never invoked.

So, why it happens and how to (in my case) save value of `p:inputTextArea` to backing bean field?

Comment: Does the problem disappear when you remove that `<p:panelGrid>`?

Comment: @BalusC , I destroyed all elements on page except `p:inputTextArea, h:form, two p:inputText and two p:commandButton` and it didn't help

Comment: Please update the question to remove irrelevant noise distracting from the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Primefaces documentation says about `readonly` attribute of `inputTextArea`

> Flag indicating that this component will prevent changes by the user.

This means that this field never will change on client and because of the setter is never called.

If you want use a `p:inputTextArea` for showing the text you can combine it with a `h:inputHidden` field where you store the same value and this hidden field can be read on backing bean.

**XHTML** code:

```
<p:inputTextarea readonly="true" autoResize="false" 
    rows="7" id="specificationsArea"
    value="#{productService.specifications}">
</p:inputTextarea>
<h:inputHidden id="specificationsHidden" value="#{productService.specificationsHidden}"/>
```

**JS** code:

```
var title = newSpecificationTitle.value, desc = newSpecificationDesc.value;
if (title == null || desc == null || title.length == 0 || desc.length == 0)
    return;
specificationsArea.value = specificationsArea.value + title + ' : ' + desc
            + ';\n';
specificationsHidden.value = specificationsArea.value + title + ' : ' + desc
            + ';\n';
```

P.S.: Sorry for my English level.